# use bootstrap data-toggle to load partial

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm very new to front end development, and I am curious how would I be able to load a partial based on the active data-toggle?

```html
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#syndication")">Syndication</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#export" >Export</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="container" ng-controller="SharedVariablesController">
    <div id="syndication" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        should load syndication partial
    </div>
    <div id="export" class="tab-pane fade">
        should load export partial
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to implement tabs?

Comment: I see the angular tag, but I don't see any angular-ness in the question. Also, maybe a typo here: `" href="#syndication")"`